# PSQLException Returning autogenerated keys is only supported for 8.2 and later servers

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to make an Insert on a table and get the autogenerated Primary Key

```
    PreparedStatement pstm = dbcon.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    pstm.setDate(1, sqlDate);
    pstm.setInt(2, knr);
    pstm.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet rs = pstm.getGeneratedKeys();
```

on the first Line I get the following Error thrown:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Returning autogenerated keys is only supported for 8.2 and later servers.
```

I have the following Maven Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

And when I use `SELECT VERSION();` on the DataBase  I get

```
PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

So I dont quite understand why I cannot get the autogenerated keys?
Am I missing something here, because from what I see, I am above Version 8.2?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: The JDBC driver 9.1 is horribly outdated, you should use the current one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately PostgreSQL JDBC drivers' versioning is very delusive.

This driver

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

was released in 2011 and the groupId had also changed.
Here is a list with supported JDBC drivers.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

Comment: Yeah thanks, looks like I was too fast simply copying the 9.x Version after a quick google search, haven't noticed that there are newer versions which have moved

Comment: Your answer would be a lot better if you include the actual correct dependency in your answer itself.

Comment: Yes, but a certain version of that driver was compiled for different Java version and JDBC standard. Because I didn't know about those I couldn't point only one concreete dependency.